# Type erasure and a kind of template method pattern

Tags: c++, templates, software-design, type-erasure

Consider the following, minimal example:

```
struct S {
    using func_t = void(*)(void *);

    template<typename T>
    static void proto(void *ptr) {
        static_cast<T*>(ptr)->f();
    }

    func_t func;
    void *ptr;
};

struct T {
    void f() {}
};

void g(S &s) {
    s.func(s.ptr);
}

int main() {
    T t;
    S s;
    s.func = &S::proto<T>;
    s.ptr = &t;
    g(s);
}
```

The pretty obvious idea is to erase the type of a bunch of objects (like `T`, that is not the only available type) to create an array of instances of `S`, then iterate over that array and invoke a predetermined member function.

So far so good, it's easy to implement and it works.
Now I would like to provide an external function to be invoked on the erased object, something that would be like this:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
static void proto(void *ptr, F &&f) {
    auto *t = static_cast<T*>(ptr);
    std::forward<F>(f)(*t);
    t->f();
}
```

Or this:

```
template<typename T>
static void proto(void *ptr, void(*f)(T &)) {
    auto *t = static_cast<T*>(ptr);
    f(*t);
    t->f();
}
```

To be invoked as:

```
s.func(s.ptr, [](auto obj){ /* ... */ });
```

A kind of template method pattern where the extra functionalities are provided by the caller instead of a derived class.
Unfortunately I cannot do that for I cannot reduce the specializations to something homogeneous to be assigned to a function pointer.

The only alternative I can see is to define a custom class like the following one:

```
struct C {
    template<typename T>
    void f(T &t) { /* ... */ }

    // ...
};
```

Where `f` dispatches somehow the call internally to the right member function, then use it as:

```
struct S {
    using func_t = void(*)(void *, C &);

    template<typename T>
    static void proto(void *ptr, C &c) {
        auto t = static_cast<T*>(ptr);
        c.f(*t);
        t->f();
    }

    func_t func;
    void *ptr;
};
```

That is not far from what I would do by using a lambda, but it's more verbose and requires me to explicitly declare the class `C`.

Is there any other valid alternative to achieve the same or is this the only viable solution?

Comment: I sense an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you give us the code that you would want to write assuming you had all the supporting template magic working perfectly?

Comment: @nwp I gave something similar. Imagine to have the (let me say) type erased array, I would like to iterate over it invoking `s.func(s.ptr, [](auto obj){ /* ... */ });`, each time with slightly different lambdas. Can I give you more details? I'm not sure how to explain it _better_. I'm sorry.

Comment: What is the common thing of all the elements in the array? Do they just have a common member function `void f()`?

Comment: @nwp They are completely unrelated types without a common base and they offer a restricted set of member functions having same names and accepting same parameters.

Comment: What is stopping you from using a `std::vector<std::function<Retval_t(Param_t)>>` and filling it with `[object](Param_t param){ return object.func(param); };` for various types of `object`? One could write a template that given a heterogeneous list of objects will return such a vector.

Comment: @nwp The fact that all `Object`s must be copy constructible in your case and they are not. Moreover `std::function` introduces overhead (with which I could leave, of course, said to avoid that someone will come running and saying - _did you measure it?_).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can enumerate the types you wish to support you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <class... Ts>
struct PseudoFunction {
    private:
    template <class T>
    static void (*function)(T &);

    template <class T>
    static void call_func(void *object) {
        return function<T>(*static_cast<T *>(object));
    }

    template <class Fun>
    static void assign(Fun) {}

    template <class Fun, class Head, class... Tail>
    static void assign(Fun fun) {
        function<Head> = fun;
        assign<Fun, Tail...>(fun);
    }

    public:
    template <class T>
    PseudoFunction(T *t)
        : object(t)
        , func(call_func<T>) {}

    template <class F>
    static void set_function(F f) {
        assign<F, Ts...>(f);
    }
    void operator()() {
        func(object);
    }

    private:
    void *object;
    void (*func)(void *);
};

template <class... Ts>
template <class T>
void (*PseudoFunction<Ts...>::function)(T &) = nullptr;

//example types that are not related and not copy constructible
//but have the same member function name and signature
struct T1 {
    T1() = default;
    T1(const T1 &) = delete;
    void func(double d) {
        std::cout << "T1: " + std::to_string(d) + '\n';
    }
};

struct T2 {
    T2() = default;
    T2(const T2 &) = delete;
    void func(double d) {
        std::cout << "T2: " + std::to_string(d) + '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;

    using PF = PseudoFunction<T1, T2>;

    std::vector<PF> funcs;
    funcs.push_back(&t1);
    funcs.push_back(&t2);

    PF::set_function([](auto &object) { object.func(3.14); });
    for (auto &f : funcs) {
        f();
    }
}
```

([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d1b0cede6ae2790))

It has decent call syntax (just that you have to specify the function before calling the objects) and some overhead of setting potentially unused function pointers.

One could probably make a wrapper that does the `set_function` and iterating over the `PF`s in one go.